# MediaPickerInstagram library - I am searching for a media picker library like instagram

Tags: android, instagram, media, image-gallery

I searched a lot and posting this question for android library which is similar like **Instagram posting**.
I got one library here is the link https://github.com/luoyiqi/MediaPickerInstagram but this library not fully done. Please some one suggest me the library which has capture photo,capture video and pick media from Gallery.

Thanks advance

Comment: Hi Fakeeraddi have you get any library for this?

Comment: There is no any media picking library like Insta for android as per my research.

Comment: https://github.com/JessYanCoding/InsGallery-  Try this its cool library which will cover most of insta camera roll feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late for the answer

I am using [this](https://github.com/JessYanCoding/InsGallery) library.
Hope it will work for you.

```
//------------------------Camera(do not change)--------------------------------------------------------------
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-beta06"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta06"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-beta06"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha13"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha13"
```

Don't forget to add these dependencies and never change them

Comment: Hi, I am facing errors using this library, could you provide your code on how you implemented this successfully, please?

Comment: What kind of error you are facing? I never faced any. I copy all the code related to it which is present in the sample project of that library. But it also works normally.

Comment: Have you added all the camerax libraries to your project? When I add a camera2 library to implement CameraXConfig.Provider in my Application it gives me an error of camera core class not found and when I add all the camerax libraries it doesn't compile and shows duplicate values when I remove the library that causes the duplicate error, it gives me other errors. I am wasting hours and hours figuring out. Could you please help me? I would really appreciate it. I am a newbie to android programming.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Welcome. If this helped you, please vote the answer.

Comment: What camerax_version should we use?

Comment: Answer is edited

Comment: Wow, it worked now. It was just an issue with the libraries' versions. Thank you so much.

Comment: It is now crashing when recording a video.

Comment: Try to copy and paste all dependencies with the same version from the project

Comment: I tried the same versions and also the different versions. I tried solutions given in the issues at the GitHub repo but still it is not resolving.

Comment: Please share the error and also check if it is crashing on another version of Android.